# Changing name if that already exists

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I change the `foldername` if there exists some other folder with that name?

I tried in the below manner but it didn't work :(

```
    private int ik;
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string folderpath = @"C:\Users\nouser\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\folders";
        string foldername = TextBox1.Text;
        string newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderpath, foldername);
        if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(folderpath, foldername)))
        {
            foldername = foldername + Convert.ToString(ik);
            ik = ik + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
            Response.Write("Folder created");
        }
    }
```

This code is able to create a new folder but unable to change the folder name from "newfolder" to "newfolder1" if "newfolder" already exists.

Comment: foldername is retrieved in each click from UI and in the 'if' you are changing the foldername but not creating anything..

Comment: You don't create a folder for foldername in the then branch.

Comment: @rontornambe - Look at the first line of my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you want something where if you try to create a folder named "foo" but a folder named "foo" exist already you want your new folder to be called "foo1"? If so you'll have to detect if the folder exists or not and create a new name for it.  You can do something like this

```
var count = 1;
var originalPath = newPath;
while(Directory.Exists(newPath)){
     newPath = originalPath + count;
     count++;
}

Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
```

This ensures that your new path doesn't already exist and if it does will ensure you get a unique name for your folder.

In your example I wasn't sure what you were doing with the variable

```
ik
```

I think thats where you were trying to create a unique directory, but what happens if you already have a newFolder1 there? This is why you should use a while loop to keep checking

Answer (score 2):

Use system.IO.Directory move

```
System.IO.Directory.Move("newfolder","newfolder1");
```

For more information see msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.move.aspx

Comment: Sorry! I don't want to rename folder! I need to change the object name of newly creating object if such object name already exists in the system/database.

Answer (score 1):

Use Move like this:

```
System.IO.Directory.Move("old name", "new name");
```

Comment: Sorry! I don't want to rename folder! I need to change the object name of newly creating object if such object name already exists in the system/database.